# Loop para executar processos de quantidade em quantidade

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Tenho uma lista de tamanho 30 no python,
Eu preciso fazer um loop para pegar 6 item dessa lista executar,
depois que finalizar os 6 executar mais 6 e assim por diante até finalizar a lista.

porém não estou encontrando uma forma de fazer isso.

```
   import os
    scripts[
    'exp1.py'
    'exp2.py'
    'exp3.py'
    'exp4.py'
    [...]
    'exp30.py'
    ]
def roda_processo(processo):
    os.system('python {}'.format(processo))
```

executar:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scripts import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processors = #[preciso que a execução ocorra aqui 6 em 6]

    pool = Pool(processes=num_processors)
    output = pool.map(roda_processo, processos)
    print(output)
```

Porque eu preciso que só rode 6 processos por vez e quando for finalizando um rodar os outros.

Comment: Não entendi direito. O `exp.py` é o código de baixo? Onde estão os 30 elementos da lista? Você quer de 6 em 6 porque o `num_processors` é 6 ou tem que ser de 6 em 6 independente do `num_processors`?

Comment: eu tenho uma lista com 30 elementos `scripts` preciso executar essa lista de processos de 6 em 6, porque tem que ser de 6 em 6 não pode executar os 30 de uma única vez.

Comment: O que o seu código faz hoje? E o que ele não faz? O que ele deveria fazer?

Comment: hoje executa todos scripts de uma vez.
eu preciso executar de 6 em 6 e na medida que for finalizando um dois 6 pega outro e vai executando até completar todos da lista.

Answer (score 4):

Não existe a menor necessidade de usar `multiprocessing`  pra iniciar um processo que vai usar `os.system` pra rodar uma shell (outro processo) que por sua vez vai rodar outro processo python pra iniciar um script!!

Dessa forma você está rodando 3 processos pra cada trabalho que deseja realizar! Bastante ineficiente e confuso.

Ao invés disso use o módulo `asyncio`. A vantagem é poder fazer uso do `asyncio.wait()` para esperar que um um dos processos finalize; Dessa forma é possível iniciar um novo processo assim que qualquer um deles terminar, em qualquer ordem, mesmo que um dos processos seja mais rápido que o outro.

```
import sys
import asyncio

scripts = [
    'exp1.py',
    'exp2.py',
    'exp3.py',
    'exp4.py',
    ...
    'exp30.py',
]

async def main():
    tarefas_rodando = set() 
    while scripts:
        # inicia até 6 scripts
        while len(tarefas_rodando) < 6 and scripts:
            script = scripts.pop()
            p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(sys.executable, script)
            tarefa = asyncio.create_task(p.wait())
            tarefas_rodando.add(tarefa)

        # espera um dos scripts acabar
        finalizadas, tarefas_rodando = await asyncio.wait(tarefas_rodando, 
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    # finalizou, espera o restante terminar
    await asyncio.wait(tarefas_rodando, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)

if sys.platform == "win32":
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(
        asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Entendi, é que nunca havia trabalhado diversos processos dessa forma.

Comment: Executei o script e deu um erro:
https://gist.github.com/braganetx/210d8873d9b060948b1eeefaa8bc637d

Comment: @JB_ parece que você está no windows, leia essa seção da documentação do `asyncio` sobre uso de subprocessos no windows: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-platforms.html#asyncio-windows-subprocess

Comment: Sim estou usando o Windows,
Vou montar um ambiente linux para executar esse processo, porque ele no servidor será executado no linux.

Comment: Consegui migrar para Linux, porém está desanexando processo:
`/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/unix_events.py:861: RuntimeWarning: A loop is being detached from a child watcher with pending handlers
  RuntimeWarning)
` não entendi o motivo de ocorrer isso, pesquisei por esse erro e vi que pode ter haver com conexão de internet, mais não é meu caso.